# How to use special characters in supervisord config file?

Tags: supervisord

I am trying to configure Supervisord with the `inet_http_server` web interface.

`/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` takes a username and password for the web interface, and I need to use a password that contains special characters like "!" and "$". However, when I start supervisor with these parameters, passwords with special characters like the dollar sign do not work. I've also tried placing the password in double quotes to no avail. I've also tried escaping the dollar sign with a back slash.

What is the correct syntax to get this to work?